# Если есть совпадение в урл, скрыть блок

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Как скрыть блок не только на одной странице, но и на страницах, входящих в эту категорию. Вот код:

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/index.php/novosti")
{
?>
<style>
#news {display:none;}
</style>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if (in_array('novosti', explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) { ?>
    <style>
        #news {display:none;}
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
if(location.pathname.indexOf('novosti') > 0){
    $("#news").css("display", "none")
}
});
```

Comment: jquery как вариант